# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited Process exited with status 1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have a RuntimeWarning error in my code it will help me if you could tell me what to fix,

btw this is discord.py

code :

`

```
            @tasks.loop(minutes=2)
            async def rated():
            channel = bot.get_channel(954343331889025035)
            messages = await channel.history(limit=10).flatten()
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            f = open("message log.txt","r")
            readfile = f.read()
            f.close()
            for message in messages:
                channel = bot.get_channel(954343331889025035)
                message = await channel.fetch_message(message.id)
                if str(message.id) not in readfile:
                if message.reactions:
                    if message.reactions[0].count >= 7:
                    x = message.reactions[0].count
                    link = message.jump_url
                    channel = bot.get_channel(1004823420732702790)
                    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.content}",description=f"**Source** \n[Jump!]({link})",color = discord.Colour.blue())
                    em.set_image(url=f"{message.attachments[0].url}")
                    em.set_author(name=f"{message.author.name}",icon_url=f"{message.author.avatar.url}")

                    await channel.send(f"⭐ {x} <#954343331889025035>",embed=em)
                    f = open("message log.txt", "a")
                    f.write("\n" + str(message.id))
                    f.close()
            @rated.before_loop
            async def before():
                await bot.wait_until_ready()
            rated.start()
```

i get the next error :

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/app/main.py", line 362, in <module>
                rated.start() 
            File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 398, in start
                self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
            File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 336, in create_task
                loop = events.get_running_loop()
            RuntimeError: no running event loop
            sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
            Process exited with status 1
            Starting process with command `python main.py`
            State changed from starting to up
```

can you tell me how can i fix it ?

it worked in vscode but when i moved it to heroku i got this error

Answer (score 0):

You need create/get loop and run it with asyncio:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html

Comment: but it works in vscode so what changed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).